# How to apply criteria to subquery (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

As is happens, after I composed my question I found the solution. Here is what I had as problem:

My database tables are:

**bookings** with such fields:
id, event_id, ...

**comments** with such fields:
id, booking_id, event_id

and **events** obviously with ID and other fields. Also **cities** which is not important for this topic

I have such working request:

```
SELECT
    bookings.id as 'booking id',
    bookings.name as 'client name',
    events.title as 'event title',
    cities.title as 'City',
FROM bookings 
    JOIN events ON events.id = bookings .event_id 
    JOIN cities on events.city_id = cities.id
WHERE bookings.status = "new"
and bookings.id not in (SELECT booking_id 
                        FROM comments 
                        WHERE booking_id <> 0 
                        and booking_id is not null
                        )
```

**I want to see bookings for such events which have less than 5 comments** in **comments** table.
I was trying to add this (to query mentioned above):

```
SELECT
<...>
events.id as MY_VARIABLE 
<...>
WHERE
<...>
and (SELECT count(id) FROM comments WHERE comments.event_id = MY_VARIABLE and booking_id <> 0 and booking_id is not null) < 10
```

This, obviously, DOES NOT WORK, and I don't know if I should make python script which will store count of comments for each event and then use this as criteria to exclude/include data from my first query

Please help, is there easy enough solution in MySQL? I can provide additional info or make this more clear in comments, if needed

Comment: You cannot refer to the output column alias in WHERE. But you may do this in HAVING.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot about "HAVING", thank you

Comment: ___I have two tables:___  Bookings, Comments, and Events? How many?? And then your query uses a table called `cities` ????

Comment: @RiggsFolly thank you, my bad. at first I was going to mention only two tables, and then mentioned other tables and forgot to change that sentence...
I mentioned cities in post, initially

Answer (score 0):

I added this to SELECT fields:

```
events.id as A,
    (SELECT count(comments.event_id)
    FROM events LEFT JOIN comments ON events.id = comments.event_id
    WHERE events.id = A and booking_id <> 0 and booking_id is not null) as 'Comment count'
```

And it worked just fine. I now have the data I needed and can filter it by comment count

Comment: It's good practice to qualify *all* column references.